Looking for techniques to Optimize a Voxel Destruction System (Roblox)
I'm currently working on a voxel destruction system for a roblox game and I'm facing some performance issues. The system works as follows:
Hitbox Generation: A hitbox is repeatedly generated at a specified position. The hitbox can be a box/rectangle or a sphere
Part Detection and Splitting: When parts are detected within this hitbox, it is split into smaller segments.
This splitting can divide the parts into (depending on certain conditions):

8 parts
4 parts
Split in half
A new hitbox is generated again at the same spot to check the new parts generated from the splitting. Then we check if they are lower than the minimum size if not we split again.

This process continues until the parts found in the hitbox reach a certain minimum size.
Once the parts are small enough, they act as debris.
While this system works, it causes slight increases in frame times during execution. I am looking for ideas and techniques to improve the performance of this system.
Current Performance Issue:
Frame times increase slightly when the destruction system is in action.
Questions:
What general techniques can be used to optimize a voxel-based destruction system?
Are there specific data structures or algorithms that can improve the efficiency of splitting?
How can I minimize the performance impact of recursively splitting voxels?
Any tips on optimizing the management of debris parts once they are created?
I appreciate any advice or suggestions on how to tackle these performance challenges. Thank you!
What I Tried:
Multithreading: I explored using multithreading to handle the recursive splitting in parallel, but in roblox setting the cframe of a part is not safe in parallel
